# Execute script in new tab command line gnome-terminal

Tags: shell-script, scripting, gnome-terminal, typescript

i want to open a new terminal and execute a script immediately to it (to set a title in the new tab) and i cannot configure this. I try:

```
gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=$varname -x ./test.sh -c "script -a -c 'ping $varname' $PATH_REPORT/$varname.log"
```

Any help how can i execute the test.sh script which contains:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${varname}\007"'
```

with the others in command i wrote?

Comment: `PROMPT_COMMAND` is only evaluated when a _prompt_ is displayed.  Since this is a non-interactive session, just do the `echo -ne ....` directly.

Comment: can you give me an example that it will run? ty (the exact command that you mean because i tried every possible way and the terminal did not opened).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your solution so that you only need to specify the hostname once.  The `test.sh` script can set the prompt directly with the `echo` command and then run the `ping` you want.

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo -ne "\033]0;$1\007"
script -a -c "ping $1" $PATH_REPORT/$1.log
```

Now you can call this with

```
gnome-terminal -x ./test.sh $varname
```

(make sure PATH_REPORT is set in the script before hand,or exported from the current shell)

If you want more complicated executions then you can adjust the `test.sh` script as you need.

Comment: yeah now the problem is that i am going to open many shells i cannot:
`gnome-terminal \
--tab-with-profile=$var1 -e "./test.sh" $var1 \
--tab-with-profile=$var2 -e "./test.sh" $var2`

Comment: With `-e` you need to specify `-e "$PWD/test.sh $var1"`.  I assume you have the profiles all set up!

Comment: If you don't need specific profiles then you can just use `--tab`; eg `gnome-terminal --tab -e "$PWD/test.sh $var1" --tab -e "$PWD/test.sh $var2"`